# How to insert apostrophe in the middle of string using string.Insert c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a bunch of string which i loop through . I want to insert an apostrophe when ever an apostrophe in any string that has apostrophe. I simply do something like below.

```
string strStatus =  "l'oreal";

index = strStatus.IndexOf("'");
strStatus.Insert(index, "  '  ");
```

I want to  have output like l''oreal. Yet this fails. I tried using escape patter

```
   strStatus.Insert(index, "  \'  ");
```

All to no avail. Please how do i achieve this? Any suggestion/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried strStatus.Replace("'", "''"); ? You can try this if "Insert" is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Insert returns a new string with the 2 apostrophes, it doesn't modify `strStatus` in any way. Your code simply discards the result of Insert.

You should try:
    string strStatus =  "l'oreal";

```
index = strStatus.IndexOf("'");
string newStatus=strStatus.Insert(index, "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in .NET (and Java), which means `Insert` does not modify `strStatus`, instead it will return a new instance which has the modification you're after.

Do this:

```
String status = "L'Oreal";
status = status.Insert( status.IndexOf('\''), "'" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in C#, so all it's methods do not modify the string itself - they return modified copy. This should work:

```
strStatus = strStatus.Insert(index, "  '  ");
```